How do you mock a call to Vercel's new 'ai/rsc' service (specifically in playwright)?
I have an application that uses 'ai/rsc' from vercel.
I want to mock the AI service for running tests (specifically in playwright).
When I look at the XHR network requests they are all going via calls to "/" which is clever.
fetch("http://localhost:3000/", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/x-component",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryw9ByQXTBBlGqBZ2Y",
    "next-action": "f16f0ef016b15f89a539b4d479bd15296fe4428f",
    "next-router-state-tree": "%5B%22%22%2C%7B%22children%22%3A%5B%22(chat)%22%2C%7B%22children%22%3A%5B%22__PAGE__%22%2C%7B%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Ctrue%5D",
    "Referer": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
  },
  "body": "------WebKitFormBoundaryw9ByQXTBBlGqBZ2Y\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"1\"\r\n\r\n{\"id\":\"eac49d1384e269655d3121553771c70380703f95\",\"bound\":null}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryw9ByQXTBBlGqBZ2Y\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"2\"\r\n\r\n{\"id\":\"42707a92b6ca00062843f58a9b44c6774cd1b1d8\",\"bound\":null}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryw9ByQXTBBlGqBZ2Y\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"0\"\r\n\r\n[{\"action\":\"$F1\",\"options\":{\"onSetAIState\":\"$F2\"}},{\"chatId\":\"NW8wbIc\",\"messages\":[{\"id\":\"mf0ZPcQ\",\"role\":\"user\",\"content\":\"Chat line 1\"},{\"id\":\"acUYFY1\",\"role\":\"assistant\",\"content\":\"Chat response line 1\"}]},\"Chat line 2\"]\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryw9ByQXTBBlGqBZ2Y--\r\n",
  "method": "POST"
});

Curiously I can't find the response in google chrome. As it's a stream I was expecting to see some way of understanding the stream parts but I can't figure it out. Importantly if I wanted to mock it how would I go about it?
